# Would too much sensor cleaning reduce image quality

Tags: sensor, cleaning

Would too much sensor cleaning (wiping) impact the sharpness, dynamic range, and color depth?

Comment: @mattdm: I'm not asking if it is risky, but I'm asking about potential impacts.

Comment: Isn't that implied in "risk"?

Comment: @mattdm: Not a risk, because I mean would the cleaning liquid bleach some very very thin layer of the sensor (or the filter on top it) and more importantly would that lead to reduction of quality in terms of sharpness, dynamic range and color depth. In the other post, I didn't find these aspects.

Comment: I don't see how that isn't a risk....

Comment: @mattdm: ok but the other question does not discusse the risk from this perspective.

Comment: It seems to. It says "so I would like to know the risk of problems, such as further image deterioration or damage to the sensor or low-pass filter" — isn't that literally, exactly what you are asking?

Comment: @mattdm: You are right, but within the responses I couldn't find anything related to what I asked.

Comment: See [How Do I “Refresh” a Question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question)

Comment: "Too much" sensor cleaning using proper methods and techniques would not. Using *incorrect* methods and techniques, even one time, certainly could.

Answer (score 0):

If done properly and with care, you shouldn't have any problems, but I wouldn't advise you to do it every day, because you could potentially damage it by accident.

If you're worried, pay a company to do it for you. Judging by your history, it seems this bothers you for over a year now..

Comment: Yes, I'm very sensitive and precise on these things.